# Aruco Ros Convention of Rotation Vector (Rxyz)

Tags: ros, camera-calibration, euler-angles, rotational-matrices, aruco

Aruco Ros prints tag id followed by keypoints, Txyz (Traslation) and Rxyz (Rotation). Rxyz has 3 angle in rad. Which angle does it represents? Is it euler angle? If yes then, out of [6 intrinsic and 6 extrinsic convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_angles) which one does it follow? Is it Rodrigues angles or something else altogether? I have a particular case for which I know the axis for tag and camera. Can I figure out their convention of Rxyz?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that aruco library uses OpenCV as backend. And if we look in the sources, we will see that it uses `cv::Rodrigues(Rvec, Rot);` internally, for example, in the code for Ogre integration. So, I suppose that in Aruco Ros Rxyz is in the same format.

For insight you can see [aruco source](https://github.com/pal-robotics/aruco_ros/blob/indigo-devel/aruco/src/aruco/marker.cpp#L146). Maybe you'll need inverse operation, but still it is good starting point.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I had looked into that before. Code is also doing one rotation after Rodrigues. Rodrigues angles themselves are hard to visualize.